# Bokeh not reading sorted Pandas Dataframe correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to make a sorted bar graph with a dual y-axis. So far, I have the graph in place but I am trying to sort it from the most to the least enrollment.

Here is the code for how I've sorted my data frame:

```
 #Merging the Two DFs
viz_df = pd.merge(totenrl_df, gpaAvg_df, on = 'Institution')

#Sorting Values based off Enrollment
viz_df = viz_df.sort_values('Total Female Enrollment', ascending = False)

#Reducing DF to exclude those who do not have enrollment numbers
viz_df = viz_df[viz_df['Total Female Enrollment'] != 0]
viz_df.head(10)
```

This yields me:
[image]
The problem I'm running into is getting Bokeh to understand this sorted graph. This is the code I have for generating my graph:

```
#Creating Output File
output_notebook()

#Setting Dimensions
p = figure(plot_width = 800, plot_height = 400)

#Creating Point Renderer
p.cross(viz_df.index,viz_df['Totals, Female: Cumulative GPA (Tot. F)'].values,line_width = 0.5, color = 'red', y_range_name = 'GPA')

#Creating alterante range for GPA
p.extra_y_ranges = {'GPA': Range1d(start = 0, end = 4.0)}
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name = 'GPA'), 'right')

#Creating Bar Values
h = viz_df['Total Female Enrollment'].values

#Adding Bar Renderer
p.vbar(x = viz_df.index, bottom = 0, top = h, width = .5)




show(p)
```

Which yields me:
[image]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I think it should be working. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What is the x-axis supposed to represent? You are using `df.index` as the x coordinate, but if you look at the left most column of your dataframe the index is not sorted the same as the `'Total Female Enrollment'` column

Comment: Sorry, it's the second left-most column that is `df.index` I believe. In any case the index is what's ordering the data points. You might try `viz_df.reset_index()` after you sort.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue. The problem is, Bokeh is referring to the index column to provide data. When you sort, Pandas doesn't automatically reset the index (you can observe this in the index column of the table you shared) so all you have to do is, after the sort, put .reset_index() and it should run fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you maybe provide some code to go with your answer, an example?